# Does anyone knows a work on Mongolian loanwords in Turkic languages?

Tags: reference-request, dictionary, turkic-languages, mongolian

Especially in Western branch of Turkic languages.

Answer (score 2):

The standard work on Turkish etymology is Clauson's "Etymological dictionary of pre-thirteenth-century Turkish".

Comment: Most of the Mongolian loan words in Western Branch (especially Oghuz languages) entered after mongolian invasion. Although I don't know the work,since he asked for Western branch, I assume that work may not be satisfactory for him.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend *ESKİ VE ORTA TÜRKÇEDE MOĞOLCA KELİMELER* by Tuncer Gülensoy. Not only does it have a good summary, it also includes lots of sources for that topic. I also recommend this paper:

- [*OSMANLICADA  MOĞOLCA  KELİMELER*](http://dergipark.ulakbim.gov.tr/iuturkiyat/article/viewFile/1023000769/pdf)

Answer (score 0):

found one research in English http://www.sosyalarastirmalar.com/cilt7/sayi32_pdf/1dil_edebiyat/tokat_feyza.pdf
according to the research, below are some words that are similar

> `castration aḫta /M. aḳda`

`golden     altun/altan`

`red        al`

`sibling    anda`
`pure       arig`
`profit     asig`
`eat        asa`
`leopard    bars`
`hero       batur`
`present    belek`
`source     bulag`
`group      buluk`
`spear      cida`
`flower     cecek`
`wise       cecen`
`face       ciray`
`secret     dalda`
`iron       temur`
`equil      deng`
`early      erden`
`knowledge  erdem`
`speak      keleci`
`braid      kekul`
`whole      lab`
`bread      manto`
`thousand   min`
`grow       os`
`beard      sahal`
`blind      sokur`
`absorb     soru`
`plate      tabag`
`land       tala`
`hell       tamu`
`chattels   tavar`
`earth      tobarak`
`net        tor`
`wedding    toy`
`law        toru`
`water      usu`
`reproduce  uru`
`big        reke`

also found another paper that list lots of words for references
http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/corff/im/Sprache/hugjilt.unx